# How to convert a Uint8Array into a boolean (bit) array without using strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm using javascript, and I'm little rusty on my bit arithmetic.

Ultimately, my goal is to convert a UInt8Array into 11-bit numbers for use with a bip39 wordlist for converting a libsodium private box key to a mnemonic (I'm building a small p2p-ish chat app).

So, my thought process is:

1. Uint8Array is returned from `libsodium.crypto_box_keypair()`
2. Convert Uint8Array into a 256bit (boolean) array
3. divide the 256bit array into 11bit buckets (2d array: ~24 x 11bits)
4. convert each 11bit array to a base 10 number (between 0 and 2047)

Steps 2, 3, and 4 can be combined into the same loop.

*The goal of all this is to efficiently convert from a Uint8Array to an array of 11bit numbers (efficient for the computer -- this hasn't been efficient for myself).*

I have this at the moment, but it isn't quite right, and feels somewhat hacky (just from steps 2 and 3, where I try to create the 11bit buckets)

```
// inspired from: https://github.com/pvorb/node-md5/issues/25
export function toUint11Array(input: Uint8Array): boolean[][] {
  let result: boolean[][] = [];
  let currentChunk: boolean[] = [];

  input.forEach(byte => {
    for (var j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
      var b = ((byte >> j) & 0x1) > 0;

      if (currentChunk.length === 11) {
        result.push(currentChunk);
        currentChunk = [];
      }

      currentChunk.push(b);
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Currently, for 2048, I get 2 11 bit arrays (expected), but the content / order is unexpected.

```
  [
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false
  ],
  [ false, true, false, false,
    false, false, false, false, 
    false, false, false
  ]
```

2048 is 0b100_000_000_000

where the 12th digit from the right is the 1 (added underscores for easier reading)

so maybe it looks like I have an endianness problem and and off by one issue? because the true in my dual array is the 13th position from the left.

though, when I test with 4096 (13 bits (0b1_000_000_000_000)), I get this:

```
  [
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false
  ],
  [
    true, false, false, false,
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false
  ],
  [
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false, false,
    false, false, false
  ]
```

Here, the `true` is 12th from the left, and 22nd from the right.

#### Update

per @bergi, who asked about endianness.

[image]

I don't know what endianness this is. :-\

#### Update 2

Thanks to @harold for coming up with the answer. I have some tests that I *think* confirm correctness.

```
  const numbers = {
    ['32']: new Uint8Array([32]),
    ['64']: new Uint8Array([64]),
    ['2048']: new Uint8Array([8, 0]),
    ['4096']: new Uint8Array([16, 0]),
    ['7331']: new Uint8Array([28, 163])
  }

  test ('toUint11Array | converts | 32 (8 bits)', function(assert) {
    const result = toUint11Array(numbers['32']);
    const expected = [32];

    assert.deepEqual(result, expected);
  });

  test ('toUint11Array | converts | 2048 (12 bits)', function(assert) {
    const result = toUint11Array(numbers['2048']);
    const expected = [8, 0];

    assert.deepEqual(result, expected);
  });

  test ('toUint11Array | converts | 4096 (13 bits)', function(assert) {
    const result = toUint11Array(numbers['4096']);
    const expected = [16, 0];

    assert.deepEqual(result, expected);
  });



 test ('toUint11Array | converts | 7331 (13 bits)', function(assert) {
    const result = toUint11Array(numbers['7331']);
    const expected = [3, 1187];

    assert.deepEqual(result, expected);
  });
```

the first 3 pass, but the last does not.

when converting a `Uint8Array(28, 163)`, I get `[796, 28]`

I'm not 100% sure that I converted 7331 into appropriate bytes correctly, but I did:
`7331 = 0b1_1100_1010_0011` split: `[1_1100, 1010_0011]` -> `[28, 163]`.

I suppose for the output, it should be: `[11, 100_1010_0011]` which is `[3, 1187]` which also doesn't match the output.

Comment: Does `crypto_box_keypair()` always return a 32-byte array?

Comment: What endianness do you need (both on bit and byte level)?

Comment: "*Steps 2, 3, and 4 can be combined into the same loop*" - I would recommend to use generator functions here, they should simplify the code a lot.

Comment: @Bergi yes, it's a 32 Byte Uint8Array
Not sure about endianness. I'd like to stick with what is being used by default (I'll post a screenshot from the console).

Generator Funciton? how so? I haven't actually written one before? (Just used them with redux sagas, and ember-concurrency)

Comment: There is no "default endianness", and your screenshot just shows a bunch of numbers.

Comment: @Bergi I have since determined that everything is little endian (I've also learned that endianness isn't cross-architecture in JS... so.. that could be fun later)

Comment: Just saying, `7331 = 0b1110010100011` is *big*-endian - the MSB first.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about architecture differences, `crypto_box_keypair` hardly does return something that represents a number, it just returns an array of bytes.

Comment: @Bergi ah, so google is big endian? (Also, I thought the endianness was determined by the left side) oh well, I'll reverse the bits and see if I can convert things. Actually, it shouldn't matter if I'm only using decimals in google's converter. :-\ hmmmm

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, I don't *think* it'll be an issue. as long as I can convert to/from the same array of bytes, I should be good.

Comment: Most human-readable integer represenations are big endian. It's representing 7331 either as `0b1110010100011` or as `0b1100010100111`. Or, on the byte level, as either `1C A3` (big) or `A3 1C` (if we know to always have 16 bit).

Comment: One problem left to solve is that 7331 is 13 bits. In bytes of 8 bit (octets), that makes 2 octets (16 bit), in bytes of 11 bit (I called them hendecads), that makes 2 hendecads (22 bit). Converting them requires padding, and you will need to decide whether you want to pad in the front or in the end and cut it off appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not as rusty on my bit arithmetic, so I propose a method without temporary boolean arrays:

- read bytes into a buffer until there are at least 11 bits
- extract 11 bits from the buffer
- repeat

Actually a funny thing happens at the end since 11 does not divide 256, I assume padding with zeroes is OK.

So maybe something like this in JavaScript (but I *am* a little rusty on my JS)

```
function toUint11Array(input) {
    var buffer = 0, numbits = 0;
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        // prepend bits to buffer
        buffer |= input[i] << numbits;
        numbits += 8;
        // if there are enough bits, extract 11bit chunk
        if (numbits >= 11) {
            output.push(buffer & 0x7FF);
            // drop chunk from buffer
            buffer = buffer >> 11;
            numbits -= 11;
        }
    }
    // also output leftover bits
    if (numbits != 0)
        output.push(buffer);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: cool, thanks for this! I need to write a couple tests, and write the inverse of this to make sure conversion is working in both directions.

Comment: actually, Assuming I did math right, I think this works. (I haven't made the inverse yet, but I just made some Uint8 to Uint11 tests. I'll update my question with results.

Comment: I found a scenario where toUint11Array fails (I think) for `7331` (but as a Uint8Array) see my `Update 2`.  I tried doing some google-assisted decimal -> binary -> decimal conversions, *that* could be where my error is in my tests. unsure atm.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli are you sure about the expected result? I get [1187, 3] which makes sense, the 3 part are the high bits

Comment: what are you using for your input array? 
I manually got `[1187, 3]`, but my test isn't getting that.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli 7331 -> [0xA3, 0x1C] (again the low part first)

Comment: yeah, so when I use those hex values, I get the correct `1187, 3`.  How did you arrive at A3 and 1C?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I typed 7331 into windows calc, it says ‭1CA3‬ so as separate bytes that would usually be A3 1C, but I guess you have some other conversion method?

Comment: yeah, an incorrect conversion method. lol. 
Cool, so I think you have successfully answered my question, and showed me I'm bad at manual decimal -> binary conversions. :-)
since I'm working with bytes, I should have just used hex notation for my tests from the beginning. haha

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for generators:

```
function* bitsFromOctetsLE(octets) {
    for (let byte of octets) {
        for (let i=0; i<8; i++) {
            yield (byte & 1);
            byte >>= 1;
        }
    }
}
function* hendecadsFromBitsLE(bits) {
    let i=0;
    let val=0;
    for (const bit of bits) {
        if (i==11) {
            yield val;
            i = val = 0;
        }
        val |= bit << (i++);
    }
    if (i > 0) yield val;
}
```

Then use them like

```
const input = libsodium.crypto_box_keypair();
const result = Array.from(hendecadsFromBitsLE(bitsFromOctetsLE(input)))
```

Comment: what's the advantage of yielding `val` and `byte & 1`?

Comment: oh I see now, when yielded, the other function evaluates.

but there is no final return value?

Comment: Advantage over what?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli The return value of a generator function call is a generator that produces the yielded values. `Array.from` will collect them into an array in the end.

Comment: ok, I figured it out, Array.from handles the yield conversion for me.

But also, it looked like I was consistently missing the last section of data. so in `hendecadsFromBitsLE`, I added a `yield val;` at the end of the function, and now your answer *yields* the same results as @harold's answer. :-)

Now I just need to figure out what's wrong with the 7331 test.

Comment: just now saw you replied to my questions. thanks! :-)